# Messed up animation in exported FBX

Tags: animation, export, rigify, .fbx

I have a simple animation which I export into FBX.
When I import it into Unity (or back into Blender), it looks different.

This is how it is supposed to look ([image]):
[image]

This is how it looks (exported FBX):
[image]

Is anyone able to explain what is the reason for this?

Additional info:

- Animal rigify armature with custom `Jaw` bone added
- Distortion around frame 50
- [FBX file if needed](https://filebin.net/4ccgjhzd5zprdxa9/Wolf.fbx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As foreword, your exported FBX is full of unnecessary things that make your file messy and heavy.

When you export, make sure you export only the selection, and only deform bones. You can also disable leaf bones if it's a final export (I.E. you will not import the rig somewhere else and edit it). And also set the FBX Armature node to Root might help with compatibility.

[image]

---

To me, it looks like your modification of the rig actually broke the rig. We can see a bunch of bones that aren't moving normally:

[image: demo gif]

Plus your model and rigs aren't aligned to begin with, and your wolf is facing the right side instead of the front side:

[image]

I'm not sure exactly what you did, it looks like you deleted some parts of the rig and added some, but it didn't go well. I will try to show a way to fix it.

### Fix rotation

First, let's fix the rotation issue. Select your mesh in Object mode and hit <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Clear parent Keep Offset.
Hit <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>90</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> to rotate that wolf, then hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Rotation. Now the mesh object is fixed. You can select the metarig and hit <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to revert its rotations to zero, and delete the rig (we'll make a new one from the metarig). Also, <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> your WGTS collections > Delete hierarchy.

### Fix rig

I create a new wolf metarig, to be sure to start from a clean working base. Feel free to start from your metarig, but it's less safe.

Select the metarig and <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into Edit Mode. Enable these options in the Armature properties to better see what you do:

[image]

1. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode and delete the face and paw bones with <kbd>x</kbd>.
2. Select `spine.011` then shift select `spine.010` and press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Disconnect Bone.
3. Move `spine.011` tail to where you want to rotate the jaw from, and hit <kbd>e</kbd> to extrude the jaw bone from there, name it `spine.012`.
4. In `spine.011`'s Bone properties > Rigify Type panel, set it to `basic.copy_chain`:
   [image]
5. Check if `spine.009`'s rig type is `spines.basic_spine`.
6. Make sure all the neck, face and jaw bones are in the Spine bone collection:
   [image]
7. In the Armature Properties > Rigify panel, set a proper rig name like `Wolf_rig` and remove the "Overwrite Existing" entries.
   [image]
8. Optional: In the Bone Collection UI subpanel, remove the three `Face` layers (you will not need them just for a jaw bone) and also the two `Paws` layers (you have nothing for paws).
9. Generate Rig.
10. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into object mode, select the mesh then armature, Ctrl P > Set Parent To Armature Deform.
11. Select the mesh and go to its mesh data properties > Vertex Groups. You already have weights made for what was your jaw and head bones in the previous rig, but they don't have the same name anymore. So rename `DEF-jaw` to `DEF-spine.012`, and `DEF-spine.010` to `DEF-spine.011`.
12. Optionally, select your rig, tab in edit mode, and rename your controller bones to what you want. But only the controllers, not the other bones.
13. Optionally, select your `spine.011` bone and lock its location channels. As we set it to non-connected child, it is otherwise free to move away from the neck with no proper deformation. The `head` bone already does that job more accurately with the rig actually deforming correctly.

Result:

[image]

### Exporting

When you want to export, first SAVE your file. Then select only your deform bones layer, then the bones inside it, then bake the animation (menu Pose > Animation > Bake Action) with only selected and clear constraints and parents enabled:

[image]

After exporting an animation, the result is preserved (left is original, right is export):

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for bunch of practical hints! Not moving ORG bones is definitely something I will pay attention to from now on. I followed the steps, but failed on setting Rigify Types (need to educate myself on that) and receiving error: `Input to rig type must be a chain of 3 or more bones`. In the end I made it work by only setting `basic.copy_chain` on `spine.010` - it still works as I'd expect though.